# Focus on parent element when clicked is not available

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, focus

```
this.focusedElBeforeOpen = document.activeElement;
```

This part of code set focus on last active element when modal is closed. I have problem when clicked element (to open modal) is in dropdown menu and after click, dropdown menu gets `display:none`. In this case i want to set focus on parent element. I need this solution in pure js (no jquery)

`open() {
        this.setSpecificContent();
        this.$modal
            .addClass(classes.isVisible)
            .removeAttr('aria-hidden')
            .removeAttr('aria-disabled')
            .siblings()
            .attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
        this.setTabIndexElementValue(-1, this.$descriptionEl);
        this.defer(() => this.$descriptionEl.focus(), time.animation);
        this.focusedElBeforeOpen = document.activeElement;
    }`

Comment: You are asking us to resolve an issue on something we can't see or see how it changes. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

You could check if the element is hidden, and if so, assign parent element's reference to `this.focusedElBeforeOpen`:

```
if (window.getComputedStyle(this.focusedElBeforeOpen).display === 'none') {
  this.focusedElBeforeOpen = this.focusedElBeforeOpen.parentElement;
}
```